# Forget loading stuff and do the unit test c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I want to skip the loading of googletagmanager from my test environnement because i won't have the rights to make it work.

The problem is, I have my tests in red because of timeout because of googletagmanager.

I am using C# ASP.NET

What can I do ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing Unit Tests then I will suggest try mocking the "googletagmanager". There should not be dependencies on external items in Unit tests.